# list of data frames from character names

Tags: r, list, character

I have a list of object names (character class) that I would like to convert to a list of objects in order to pass them to a loop. For example,

If I have many vectors:

```
subA<-c(1,2)
subB<-c(3,4)
subC<-c(9,5)
subD<-c(4,7)
```

I can get the names from

```
subnames<-ls(pattern="sub*")

> subnames
[1] "subA" "subB" "subC" "subD"
```

But I would like a list of the actual vectors, such as in

```
subvecs<-list(subA,subB,subC,subD)

> subvecs
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 3 4

[[3]]
[1] 9 5

[[4]]
[1] 4 7
```

Is there a way to do this without rewriting the whole list without quotes? It would be very time consuming with 400+ data frames. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?get` is what you want

```
lapply(subnames, get)
```

Comment: You can do `mget(subnames)`